# how to Pick random GameObject in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, random

I'm making an endless runner game, and I have 4 types of terrain I want to auto-generate.
the auto-generation works, but I want to select a random terrain but I can't figure out how.
I have tried this:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlatformManager: MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    private GameObject[] _platformPrefabs;
    [SerializeField]
    private int _zedOffset;


    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        randomTerrain();
    }

    public void RecyclePlatform(GameObject Platform)
    {
        Platform.transform.position = new Vector3(0, 0, _zedOffset);
        _zedOffset += 12;

    }

    public void randomTerrain()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < _platformPrefabs.Length; i++)
        {
            Instantiate(_platformPrefabs[Random.Range(0, 3)], new Vector3(0, 0, i * 12), Quaternion.Euler(0, 90, 0));
            _zedOffset += 12;
        }
    }

}
```

but it only selects the first game object every time except the first initiation. how can I make it select randomly?

[image: Inspector view of script]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The random number generator is not really random; it only generates a pseudo-random stream based on a given seed. If this seed isn't initialized, that could explain why you're getting the same result each time. To initialize the random state you'll need to use [`Random.InitState`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Random.InitState.html).

A typical approach is to use the system clock for random number generators. Games like Minecraft actually let you specify this seed so that the same seed = the same randomly generated content.

```
Random.InitState(System.DateTime.Now.Ticks);
```

Comment: About the need to call `Random.InitState`? If that's what you mean, look up the topic of PRNGs, for example: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_number_generator

Comment: This is assuming that the issue is that `Random.Range(0, 3)` is returning the same value(s) each time.